# 'Incorrect datetime value[...]' quando uso o bindParam ou bindValue

Tags: php, sql, binding

Estou tentando inserir um cadastro no banco de dados da seguinte forma (PHP)

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tb_teste` (`estrutura`, `foto`, `data_cadastro`) VALUES (':estrutura', ':foto', ':data_cadastro')";

    $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $sql->bindParam(":estrutura", $estrutura, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(":foto", $foto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(":data_cadastro", $data_cadastro, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $retorno = $sql->execute();
```

Já tentei com `bindValue`, já tentei sem utilizar o último parametro `PDO::PARAM_STR`, já tentei converter para Timestamp, converti antes de mandar para o PHP (no jQuery), converti de várias formas diferentes no PHP e nada funcionou, continuo recebendo o erro:

> Incorrect datetime value: ':data_cadastro' for column 'data_cadastro'
>   at row 1

A única coisa que eu fiz e inseriu no banco, foi isso:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tb_teste` (`estrutura`, `foto`, `data_cadastro`) VALUES (':estrutura', ':foto', '$data_cadastro')";

$sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$sql->bindParam(":estrutura", $estrutura, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":foto", $foto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

colocando a variável da data direto na query não deu erro e inseriu a data no campo corretamente, porém os outros campos ficaram com o valor `:estutura`,`:foto`

OBS: valor exibido no var_dump($data_cadastro):

> C:\wamp64\www\TESTE\controllers\painel\testeController.php:57:string '1995-11-14 00:00:00'

Ou seja, quando tento utilizar o bindParam ou bindValue a inserção não funciona, mas se o valor é inserido na query, funciona corretamente.

Obrigado!

Comment: pode mostrar o valor da variável `data_cadastro`? me parece ser um problema de formato de data

Comment: @RicardoPontual O valor da variável é '1995-11-14 00:00:00', atualizei ali no post também

Comment: vc converte a data do formato `dd/mm/YYYY` para `YYYY-mm-dd` ? parace que tem um erro na conversão.

Comment: @rray eu consegui inseir o valor da variável $data_cadastro no banco, mas só colocando a variável direto na query sql, como no segundo exemplo... o erro só ocorre quando passa pelo bindParam

Comment: humm não está faltando preparar essa query? algo como `$sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO .....`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual já estou fazendo isso, vou atualizar ali inclusive

Comment: No primeiro exemplo tem aspas simples sobrando,  `':data_cadastro')`, não vai aspas no place holder.

Comment: Pra que o ":"? `$sql->bindParam("estrutura", $estrutura, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam("foto", $foto, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @MauryDeveloper segui a documentação do PHP https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Na verdade falei das aspas,são inútil,acabei apagando o `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dê uma olhada no código abaixo:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_teste (estrutura, foto, data_cadastro) VALUES (:estrutura, :foto, :data_cadastro)");    
$sql->bindValue(':estrutura', $estrutura);
$sql->bindValue(':foto', $foto);
$sql->bindValue(':data_cadastro', $data_cadastro);
$retorno = $sql->execute();
```

---

Note que troquei o método `bindParam` para `bindValue`, mas por que?

O método `bindParam` usa a **referência** da varíavel e não o seu valor como o método `bindValue` propõe. Exemplo:

```
$estrutura = 'Alicerce';
$sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_teste (estrutura) VALUES (:estrutura)");    
$sql->bindParam(':estrutura', $estrutura);
$estrutura = 'Foo Bar';
$retorno = $sql->execute(); // INSERT INTO tb_teste (estrutura) VALUES ('Foo Bar')"
```

No seu caso, utilizar os dois métodos não interfere no resultado mas expliquei isso para que você entenda a diferença entre eles.

E outra ressalva é o método [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php). Você deve utilizá-lo para **preparar** a instrução SQL com os parâmetros definidos que devem ser executados pelo método [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php). Assim, os placeholders inseridos na string serão substituídos pelos valores das variáveis após as validações feitas pelo PDO.

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou!!! Estou a manhã toda apanhando pra isso e era só tirar as aspas

Comment: Victor só "tenta dessa forma" não é uma boa explicação para uma resposta, pode detalhar o que "essa forma" tem que resolve o problema?

Comment: Você está certo @RicardoPontual. Resposta atualizada!